# JSON/Jave not updating innerHTML onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#domaincheckbutton').click(function() {
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = "Please wait ...";
    var val = $('#domain').val();
    $.get('http://www.example.com/domainsearch.php', {domain: val}, function(data) {         

    result = $.parseJSON(data);
    $("input[name='domainresults']").val(result.domainresults);
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = val(result.domainresults);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="text" id=domain name="domain" value="" />
<button id="domaincheckbutton" name="domaincheckbutton" >Check NOW</button>
<input type="text" name="domainresults" value="" readonly="readonly" />
<h2 id="finalMessage"></h2>
```

With my code I am not able to update/echo finalMessage second time.

This is working: `finalMessage.innerHTML = "Please wait ...";`

**I can't get this working**: `finalMessage.innerHTML = val(result.domainresults);`

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improper setting of the results. try this.

```
finalMessage.innerHTML = result.domainresults;
```

Comment: If it worked for you don't forget to mark me as the solution! Thanks and enjoy!